# How can I clean up my eclipse project after deleting a .java whose .class file still seems to be somewhere?

Tags: java, eclipse, .class-file

So, I deleted a couple of `.java` files from within eclipse because I didn't need them anymore. However for some reason another class still uses them and compiles without a problem. When I go to the declaration of the constructor of one of the deleted classes a `.class` file opens of that class even though I thought they got deleted by eclipse when I deleted their `.java` files.

I have tried to clean the project and I tried to find the `.class` file using the system file explorer in the folders that are listed in

`project > properties > resource > linked resources. However I couldn't find them.`

Now, since I deleted those files/classes there should be a compile time error wherever they are used but everything compiles without an error, even using the code that should've gotten deleted. A colleague that recently joined the project does receive compile time errors, since he doesn't have those class files. And I want to get them too, so I can fix the code where the classes were used. Of course he could show me the lines of code that are affected but if this happens again he would probably be affected as well as he would have the class files by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Someone built a .jar file I didn't know of which contained a lot of old code.
I found it by right clicking the constructor and selecting

> references>project

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following

> *Go to project > properties > Java Build path >Source*

under that you can find Default Output Folder section, simply delete the classes folder under that location with in your project.

Try cleaning the project.

Or

Simply close the eclipse and reopen it again, sometime this would work for me.
Hope it resolves your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you just deleted the sources, they binaries would still be there.  So open the `Navigator View` and go to the project in question.  Look for the `bin` directory and delete the appropriate class files.  Otherwise, delete the project itself.

You should also ensure that no other programs depend on those class files.